# Не проходит по условиям

Tags: c, if, условия, ввод

Есть функция:

```
// Добавить n байт слов
struct output* WordList_Add_Word_S(unsigned long long int ByteLimit, struct wordlist* WordList){

    // Переменные
    bool exitkey = false;    // Выйти из цикла
    char tmpword[257];       // Временный контейнер для слова
    char tmpchar;            // Временный контейнер для символа
    unsigned long int pos;   // Текущая позиция

    struct output * SpaceList = (struct output*)malloc(sizeof(struct output)); // Спэйс лист

    // Начальная инициализация
    pos = 0;
    SpaceList->Spaces = (unsigned long *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long));
    SpaceList->Spaces[0] = 0;
    SpaceList->RichEnd = false;

    // Запуск цикла
    while (exitkey != true){
        // Считывание символа
        if (scanf("%c", &tmpchar) == 0) {
            // Ввод закончился
            SpaceList->RichEnd = true;
            tmpword[pos] = 0;
            if (pos != 0) WordList_Add_Word(tmpword, WordList);
            exitkey = true;
        } else if ((tmpchar >= '0')&&(tmpchar <= 'Z')) {
            // Если буква
            tmpword[pos] = tolower(tmpchar);
            pos++;
        } else if ((tmpchar < '0')&&(tmpchar != '\n')&&(tmpchar != '$')&&(pos > 0)) {
            // Если пробел
            tmpword[pos] = 0;
            ByteLimit = ByteLimit - (pos+1);
            pos = 0;
            WordList_Add_Word(tmpword, WordList);
        } else if (tmpchar == '\n') {
            // Если переход на новую строку
            // Добавляем инфу о строке
            SpaceList->Spaces[0]++;
            SpaceList->Spaces = (unsigned long int*)realloc(SpaceList->Spaces, (SpaceList->Spaces[0]+1)*sizeof(unsigned long int));
            SpaceList->Spaces[SpaceList->Spaces[0]] = WordList->Count;
            // Если у нас в буфере еще лежит слово
            if (pos > 0) {
                tmpword[pos] = 0;
                ByteLimit = ByteLimit - (pos+1);
                pos = 0;
                WordList_Add_Word(tmpword, WordList);
            }
        } else if (tmpchar == '$') exitkey = true;

        // Ограничитель на размер памяти
        if ((ByteLimit <= 257)&&(pos == 0)) exitkey = true;

    }
```

Я подаю на ввод 'w', тут условие не выполняется:

```
if (scanf("%c", &tmpchar) == 0) {
```

НО! После вместо того, чтобы пройти условие:

```
} else if ((tmpchar >= '0')&&(tmpchar <= 'Z'))
```

Программа резко улетает сразу вниз, к:

```
if ((ByteLimit <= 257)&&(pos == 0)) exitkey = true;
```

Не совсем понимаю - почему так и как исправить?

Можете помочь?

Comment: Ссылка на весь проект: https://yadi.sk/d/oVYieTwkWGux2A

Comment: А вы проверяете, что в `tmpchar`? Может, там с предыдущего ввода `\n` в буфере сидит?...

Comment: @Harry, если верить отладчику - там сидит 'w'

Comment: @Harry, меня удивляет, почему не проходит по условиям. Отладчик сразу переходит вниз. Он же по идее должен остановится на else if. Но такого НЕ происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что я перепутал расположение букв в алфавите.

**Z** идет РАНЬШЕ **z**